# Why by passing it in as a parameter to a .then method, can I do bind a pre-existing getter-setter?

Tags: mithril.js

> You can bind a pre-existing getter-setter by passing it in as a
>   parameter to a .then method:

**OK**

```
var users = m.prop([]); //default value
m.request({method: "GET", url: "/user"}).then(users).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(users());
});
```

**NG**

```
var users = m.prop([]); //default value
m.request({method: "GET", url: "/user"}).then(function(users) {
    console.log(users);
    console.log(users()); //Uncaught TypeError: users is not a function
});
```

---

**Why  by passing it in as a parameter to a .then method, can I do bind a pre-existing getter-setter ?**

The specifications of this grammar is Promise?
or
The specifications of this grammar is Mithril?

※I can understand m.prop() is getter-setter.

---

**Of what kind of processing is running against Promise object internally?**

And implementation is which part of the library code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of normal Promise behaviour. A function passed to `then` will be executed when the Promise resolves and have the Promise value passed to it. An `m.prop` is a getter/setter which will set it's internal value to whatever is passed in, and returns it.

In the first example, the first `then` assigns the Promise value to `users`, and the next `then` executes a function which receives the Promise value as the first argument (`data`), and logs it, along with the return value of `users`, which is the same thing.

In the second example, the second `then` function names it's argument `users`: this means that within that function, `users` refers to the Promise value instead of the `m.prop`. Because you have given the variable the same name as the `m.prop`, you can no longer refer to that `m.prop`.